# MaterialUI - Select Underline Color

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I'm playing around with MaterialUI and I'm wondering how can I change the underline and text color of the `Select` component when an item is being selected? Currently, after I pick an option, the underline & label is blue while the background is gray. Is there a way I can customize the underline and label color?

I don't see an `underline` CSS API option in the documentation [here](https://material-ui.com/api/select/) so I'm a bit stumped as to where I can change these stylings.

Thanks for your help in advance!

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to achieve this is building your own theme using the theme provider as documented here
[Themes Provider](https://material-ui.com/customization/themes/)

You can also [Override](https://material-ui.com/customization/overrides/) the style especially if you need to only change the behavior per component.

My advice is that you build your own theme(first one). you don't have to change everything too just the ones that you want to change the other styles will apply defaultly.

Answer (score 2):

This is pretty hack-y but if you just want this done quick and dirty, you could add a rule in your CSS that uses fuzzy class selectors.

```
div[class="^=MuiInput-underline"]:hover:not(div[class="^=MuiInput-disabled"]):not(div[class="^=MuiInput-focused"]):not(div[class="^=MuiInput-error"]):before
```